# Why do my tiles render like this in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

This code here generates a tiled map

```
for tiley in range(0,len(level)):
    for tilex in range(0,len(level[tiley])):        
        for tiletype in level[tiley]:
            if tiletype == 0:
                screen.blit(air, ((tilex*50,tiley*50)))
            if tiletype == 1:
                screen.blit(grass, ((tilex*50,tiley*50)))
```

from this 2D list.

```
level = [[1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]]
```

The pygame window, however, displays [a different tilemap entirely from the list provided.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm4Ul.png) Why does it do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an extra level of iteration beyond what you need; you only want to loop for x and y, and blit once at each coordinate. Like this:

```
for tiley in range(len(level)):
    for tilex in range(len(level[tiley])):
        if level[tiley][tilex] == 0:
            screen.blit(air, (tilex * 50, tiley * 50))
        else:
            screen.blit(grass, (tilex * 50, tiley * 50))
```

However, you could also make your code cleaner, I think, by avoiding the `range(len(...))` [antipattern](https://treyhunner.com/2016/04/how-to-loop-with-indexes-in-python/) and removing some repetition:

```
for y, row in enumerate(level):
    for x, cell in enumerate(row):
        tile = grass if cell else air
        screen.blit(tile, (x * 50, y * 50))
```